# Python & Sympy : How can we adjust the coordinate plane so that the X-axis and Y-axis are equal in length?

Tags: python, math, graph, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I'm trying to plot the graphs of some mathematics equations using `Sympy`.

The graphs representing the equations look fine but when I checked the indexes on both the `X-axis` & the `Y-axis`, they are not equal. In other words, the `Y-axis` might represent twice the length of the `X-Axis`. You can check the picture below for a better visual understanding.

So my question is: How can we adjust the coordinate plane so that the `X-axis` and `Y-axis` are equal in length?

Thank you

Code :

```
formula = x**2 - 5*x + 9
plot( formula )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `aspect_ratio` keyword argument that allows you to achieve what you want by specifying `aspect_ratio=(1, 1)` (same aspect ratio on both axis). You might also want to play with `xlim` and `ylim` to center the view:

```
formula = x**2 - 5*x + 9
plot( formula, aspect_ratio=(1, 1), xlim=(-2.5, 7.5), ylim=(0, 10) )
```